# Downloading GeoJSON boundaries using SPARQL from publicly available data

Tags: sparql, rdf, geojson, linked-data, opendata

I'm interested in downloading some boundary files from [**statistics.gov.scot**](http://statistics.gov.scot/), which is an official statistical repository for sharing statistical data that utilises SPARQL queries.

## Background

[**Statistics.gov.scot**](http://statistics.gov.scot/) provides access to GeoJSON boundaries for number of administrative and statistical geographies, like [local authority administrative boundaries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_government_in_Scotland) or [health boards](http://www.gov.scot/Topics/Health/NHS-Workforce/NHS-Boards). In my particular case I'm interested in download a data set with GeoJSON boundaries pertaining to **data zones**. **Data zones** are statistical geographies developed for the purpose of disseminating life outcomes data on a small area level. When accessed via the [**statistics.gov.scot**](http://statistics.gov.scot/) sample data zone looks like that:

[image: Sample data zone]

*The geography and the related data can be accessed [here](http://statistics.gov.scot/doc/statistical-geography/S01000001). The corresponding GeoJSON data is available [here](http://statistics.gov.scot/boundaries/S01000001.json).*

## Problem

Data zones are available in two iterations, on produced in 2004 and another one updated recently. I would like to download first iteration produced in *2004*. Following the information on the [*statistical entities*](http://statistics.gov.scot/doc/statistical-entity/S01), I drafted the following query:

```
PREFIX entity: <http://statistics.data.gov.uk/def/statistical-entity#>
PREFIX boundaries: <http://statistics.gov.scot/boundaries/>

SELECT ?boundary 
    WHERE {
        entity:introduced <http://reference.data.gov.uk/id/day/2004-02-01>
  }

LIMIT 1000
```

which returns the following error message:

> ```
> Error There was a syntax error in your query: Encountered " "}" "} "" at line 7,
> column 3. Was expecting one of: <IRIref> ... <PNAME_NS> ... <PNAME_LN> ...
> <BLANK_NODE_LABEL> ... <VAR1> ... <VAR2> ... "true" ... "false" ... <INTEGER> ...
> <DECIMAL> ... <DOUBLE> ... <INTEGER_POSITIVE> ... <DECIMAL_POSITIVE> ...
> <DOUBLE_POSITIVE> ... <INTEGER_NEGATIVE> ... <DECIMAL_NEGATIVE> ...
> <DOUBLE_NEGATIVE> ... <STRING_LITERAL1> ... <STRING_LITERAL2> ...
> <STRING_LITERAL_LONG1> ... <STRING_LITERAL_LONG2> ... "(" ... <NIL> ... "[" ...
> <ANON> ... "+" ... "*" ... "/" ... "|" ... "?" ...
> ```

when tested via the endpoint: [**http://statistics.gov.scot/sparql**](http://statistics.gov.scot/sparql).

### Comments

Ideally, I would like to develop other queries that would enable me to source other statistical geographies by using the `entity:` prefix. This should be possible as the `entity:` will contain information on the available geographies (name, acronym, date of creation).

---

The query:

```
PREFIX entity: <http://statistics.data.gov.uk/def/statistical-entity#>
PREFIX boundaries: <http://statistics.gov.scot/boundaries/>

SELECT DISTINCT ?boundary ?shape WHERE {
  ?shape entity:firstcode ?boundary
}

LIMIT 1000
```

Got me to something that looks like a list of desired geographies but I'm struggling to source the GeoJSON boundaries.

Comment: It seems that neither *statistics.gov.scot*, nor *statistics.data.gov.uk* do not contain data zones boundaries as [wkt-](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) or string literals. However, one could easily construct URIs of geojson-files with the following query.

Comment: @StanislavKralin Why don’t you make it answer, it seems like a good approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither *statistics.gov.scot* nor *statistics.data.gov.uk* contains data zones boundaries as [WKT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) or string literals.

However, with the following query, one could easily construct URLs of the  GeoJSON files that are used on resources' pages:

```
PREFIX pref1: <http://statistics.data.gov.uk/def/statistical-entity#>
PREFIX pref2: <http://statistics.gov.scot/id/statistical-entity/>
PREFIX pref3: <http://statistics.data.gov.uk/def/boundary-change/>
PREFIX pref4: <http://reference.data.gov.uk/id/day/>
PREFIX pref5: <http://statistics.data.gov.uk/def/statistical-geography#>
PREFIX pref6: <http://statistics.gov.scot/id/statistical-geography/>
PREFIX pref7: <http://statistics.gov.scot/boundaries/>

SELECT ?zone ?name ?json {
   ?zone pref1:code pref2:S01 .
   ?zone pref3:operativedate pref4:2004-02-01
   OPTIONAL { ?zone pref5:officialname ?name }
   BIND (CONCAT(REPLACE(STR(?zone), STR(pref6:), STR(pref7:)), ".json") AS ?json)
} ORDER BY (!bound(?name)) ASC(?name)
```

After that, one could easily retrieve GeoJSON files using `wget -i` or something like this.

**Some explanation**

You should use `<http://statistics.data.gov.uk/def/boundary-change/operativedate>` instead of `<http://statistics.data.gov.uk/def/statistical-entity#introduced>`, the latter property is rather a class property:

```
SELECT * WHERE {
    ?S <http://statistics.data.gov.uk/def/statistical-entity#introduced> ?date .
    ?S <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label> ?label
}
```

The second generation data zones are dated by `2014-11-06`:

```
SELECT ?date (COUNT(?zone) AS ?count) WHERE {
    ?zone
        <http://statistics.data.gov.uk/def/statistical-entity#code>
            <http://statistics.gov.scot/id/statistical-entity/S01> ;
        <http://statistics.data.gov.uk/def/boundary-change/operativedate>
            ?date 
} GROUP BY ?date
```

Analogously, if you need URLs of corresponding GeoJSON files, your query should be:

```
SELECT ?zone ?name ?json {
   ?zone pref1:code pref2:S01 .
   ?zone pref3:operativedate pref4:2014-11-06 .
   ?zone pref5:officialname ?name 
   BIND (CONCAT(REPLACE(STR(?zone), STR(pref6:), STR(pref7:)), ".json") AS ?json)
} ORDER BY ASC(?name)
```

You do not need `OPTIONAL`, because all second generation data zones have "official names".

---

Probably [this page](https://data.gov.uk/dataset/data-zone-boundaries-2011) on *data.gov.uk* will be interesting for you.
There also exists [opendata.stackexchange.com](https://opendata.stackexchange.com) for questions related to open data.

**Update**

As of May 2018, one can retrieve data zones boundaries as WKT:

```
PREFIX pref1: <http://statistics.data.gov.uk/def/statistical-entity#>
PREFIX pref2: <http://statistics.gov.scot/id/statistical-entity/>
PREFIX pref3: <http://statistics.data.gov.uk/def/boundary-change/>
PREFIX pref4: <http://reference.data.gov.uk/id/day/>
PREFIX pref5: <http://statistics.data.gov.uk/def/statistical-geography#>
PREFIX pref6: <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#>


SELECT ?zone ?name ?geometry {
   ?zone pref1:code pref2:S01 .
   ?zone pref3:operativedate pref4:2014-11-06 .
   ?zone pref5:officialname ?name .
   ?zone pref6:hasGeometry/pref6:asWKT ?geometry .
} ORDER BY ASC(?name)
```

Answer (score 5):

The first query is missing the subject.  A SPARQL query defines a set of triple patterns - a subject, predicate, and object - to match an RDF graph.  To turn your WHERE clause into a SPARQL triple pattern, try:

```
?boundary entity:introduced <http://reference.data.gov.uk/id/day/2004-02-01>
```

Comment: Thanks for showing the interest in my modest problem. Running this query gave ma a table with one row and this value: `http://statistics.gov.scot/id/statistical-entity/S01` .

Comment: OK, and if you want to see what information you have about that entity, then add the triple pattern {?boundary ?p ?o}, which give you all property/object pairs and you can choose which ones you really want to query for.

Comment: `<http://statistics.data.gov.uk/def/boundary-change/operativedate>`, not `<http://statistics.data.gov.uk/def/statistical-entity#introduced>`.